# My websites load when I restart php-fpm apache

Tags: apache, cpanel, whm

I am using centos7 and I installed whm and so far I have no problem with Apache
I maintain 22 websites on this server but I have a big problem
Every few hours, it is not known exactly how many hours.
No site or page will open at all, and if I restart the PHP-FPM service, the problem will be temporarily resolved.
And all sites work fine but after a few hours the same problem occurs again and I have to restart PHP-FPM.
The interesting thing is that no error is displayed and only the sites are not opened. thank you for your help